# Open first View based on condition

Tags: swift

I want my app to check at start conditionaly if a variable is correct or not. Based on that it should either go to an intro screen (where he can select a variable in my case select a team) or it should start the main view. After searching i found this code and edited it.

But there still seems to be problems. First of all I dont have two identifier. The Intro has one but not the main view. My main View is called WeatherViewController and the Intro screen is called FirstScreenViewController.

I also added a picture of my Main.storyboard.
I also googled a lot about conditional UINavigationController but I can only understand with a video and did not found a video about it.

I tried to use the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651854/display-a-particular-viewcontroller-in-xcode-swift-using-if-else-conditional-sta).

[image: main.Storyboard]

```
 var id = hello ? "goToIntro" : "???"
      self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
      let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let WeatherViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.FirstScreenViewController(withIdentifier: WVC has no identifier??) as UIViewController
      self.window?.rootViewController = WeatherViewController
      self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
       if hello {
          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToIntro", sender: self)
        } else {
    /here nothing should happen. It should open the Main View
          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "???", sender: self)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply repeat the steps you did for creating the segue `goToIntro`.

1. Add a new `UIViewController` (`MainViewController`) in your storyboard.
2. Add a segue and give it an identifier.
3. Provide the identifier value in the else condition of the code that you've shown in your post to perform the segue to the `UIViewController` that you've just created.

The final code should look something like this:

```
var id = hello ? "goToIntro" : "goToMain"
guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let weatherViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
window?.rootViewController = weatherViewController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
weatherViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: id, sender: self)
```

You don't need the `if else` block since the `id` is already determined using the `?` ternary operator.

Comment: Thank you. But why do I need to create a new UIViewController when I already have two? The White one if the variable is right. The Blue one if the variable is wrong. Would it not lead to a third screen if I would create a third UIVC?

Comment: If you just want to stay on the first screen you could remove the else block entirely and it should be fine. But, my understanding was you wanted to segue into `MainViewController` from `IntroViewController`.

Comment: It looks like I said something wrong. I just want to show White View if the variable I check is ok. If its not ok I want to show the Blue View which is the Main View. (I guess). I will check and write here what happened

Comment: Oh no I get a lot of errors. 1. use of unresolved identifier 'hello' 2. Expected var keyword in property declaration. 3. Cannot use instance member mainStooryboard within property initiliazer 4. conscecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ;

Comment: `hello` is your condition that you need to provide. You seem to have pasted this code in the wrong place, that's the reason for the others. It needs to be in  a method of AppDelegate or SceneDelegate accordingly.

Comment: It is inside a class. https://s12.directupload.net/images/200815/z5wtni9d.png