# Black Background with SceneDelegate and First View

Tags: swift, swift5

I try to set a View as first view and get a black background. But it should be red.
This is my SceneDelegate:

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = MainNavigationController()
        
    }
```

This is my MainNavigationController

```
import UIKit

class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need the `window` to be declared with `windowScene` initializer instead of the `frame` initializer.

```
guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
```

Note: Also, make sure storyboard is disabled if you're loading `rootViewController` programmatically.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have another question. If I choose another View it only shows the Backround Jpeg. For example now I want to show this WeatherViewController() but it doesnt show the icons etc. like here. It shown only the blue Jpeg. https://i.ibb.co/sjmRYv7/Bildschirmfoto-2020-08-16-um-14-57-22.png

Comment: I think I've already given an approach on how to set the `rootViewController` based on a condition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63428072/7098650).

Comment: Right now I have some different problem. It doesnt show the View correctly. There are things missing. The picture I added few comments ago should be shown. But it only shows the blue Background. The Problem with conditional View I will solve later.

Comment: Why don't you ask this in another question? Avoid asking follow-up questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `makeKeyAndVisible()`  after setting root Also assign `window scene` to window ...

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    

        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = MainNavigationController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have another question. If I choose another View it only shows the Backround Jpeg. For example now I want to show this WeatherViewController() but it doesnt show the icons etc. like here. It shown only the blue Jpeg Background. https://i.ibb.co/sjmRYv7/Bildschirmfoto-2020-08-16-um-14-57-22.png