# Display View based on condition at start

Tags: swift, swift5

[I want to do the same thing like this person here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651854/display-a-particular-viewcontroller-in-xcode-swift-using-if-else-conditional-sta) But the code in the result is 4 years old.
I want to open viewcontroller1 if true stay on page if wrong. With IOS 13 AppDelegate.swift is not responsible anymore for this. I also cant find any tutorials maybe because it is to new. I work with Storyboard not SwiftUI. Any suggestions? I read somethings about changing SceneDelegate.swift

```
if x = true {
  //segue to viewcontroller1
} else {
  //stay on this page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your SceneDelegate's `scene(_ , willConnectTo:, options:)`, initiate the window and assign an appropriate view controller instance based on your desired condition to its `rootViewController`.

```
guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)

if condition {
    window?.rootViewController = initiateViewControllerA()
} else {
    window?.rootViewController = initiateViewControllerB()
}
    
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```